# Leaflet.js - How can I draw a polygon that automatically covers a group of markers?

Tags: maps, leaflet, layer

I´m working with Leaflet.js and I have a lot of markers but I want to get a polygon drawn automatically containing a specific group of markers.

There´s an image:

[image]

Every marker has a specific radio, so if a use it, would be like this:

[image]

but I don't want that, I want an area that contains markers, I don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create a convex hull.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215137/how-to-create-a-convex-hull-with-leaflet-points:

"The easiest way to do this with javascript is to use Turf.js's convex functionality."

A working sample - http://bl.ocks.org/ebrelsford/c31f61d39d2cd559e18a